# Combine values of two XML files by IDs using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have two XML files which I want to transform into HTML using a single XSL file. In the `elements.xml` I've got a part which combines values from these XML files by ids. Now in my HTML file, I want to present every `<element>` as a separate `<div>` in which I want to list names of effects that are linked in `<linkedId>`. I assume there would be some extensive use of variables but I can't get my head around it.

For example, output for the first element should look like this:

```
<div>
 <div><p>NAME2</p></div>
 <div><p>NAME1</p></div>
</div>
```

**elements.xml**

```
<elements>
  <listOfElements>
    <element>
      <id>ID-element-1</id>
      *some data*
    </element>
    <element>
      <id>ID-element-2</id>
      *some data*
    </element>
     (...)
 </listOfElements>
 <linkedIds>
   <linkedId>
     <idOfElement>ID-element-1</idOfElement>
     <idOfEffect>ID-effect-2</idOfEffect>
     <idOfEffect>ID-effect-1</idOfEffect>
   <linkedId>
   <linkedId>
     <idOfElement>ID-element-2</idOfElement>
     <idOfEffect>ID-effect-2</idOfEffect>
     <idOfEffect>ID-effect-4</idOfEffect>
     <idOfEffect>ID-effect-7</idOfEffect>
    <linkedId>
     (...)
 </linkedIds>
</elements>
```

**effects.xml**

```
<effects>
 <effect>
   <idEffect>ID-effect-1</idEffect>
   <name>NAME1</name>
 </effect>
   <effect>
   <idEffect>ID-effect-2</idEffect>
   <name>NAME2</name>
 </effect>
 <effect>
   <idEffect>ID-effect-4</idEffect>
   <name>NAME4</name>
 </effect>
 <effect>
   <idEffect>ID-effect-7</idEffect>
   <name>NAME7</name>
 </effect>
</effect>
```

**transform.xsl**

```
<xsl:template match="elements">
  <div>
    <xsl:for-each select="elements/element">
      <xsl:variable name="ElementID" select='linkedIds/linkedId/idOfElement'/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('effects.xml')/effects"/>
      ???
    </xsl:for-each>
   </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="effects">
    <xsl:for-each select="effects/effect">
     <div>
       <p><xsl:value-of select="name"/></p>
     </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define two keys

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="linkedIds/linkedId" use="idOfElement"/>

<xsl:key name="k2" match="effect" use="idEffect"/>
```

then in the template matching `element` use them

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="effects-url" select="'test2016051804.xml'"/>   
    <xsl:variable name="effects-doc" select="document($effects-url)"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="k1" match="linkedIds/linkedId" use="idOfElement"/>

    <xsl:key name="k2" match="effect" use="idEffect"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//element"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="elements/listOfElements/element">
        <div>
            <xsl:variable name="linkedIds" select="key('k1', id)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$effects-doc">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k2', $linkedIds/idOfEffect)/name"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- with XSLT 2.0 you can simply use
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k2', key('k1', id), $effects-doc)"/>
        for the above 4 lines
    -->
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="effect/name">
        <div>
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way the inputs

```
<elements>
    <listOfElements>
        <element>
            <id>ID-element-1</id> *some data* </element>
        <element>
            <id>ID-element-2</id> *some data* </element>
    </listOfElements>
    <linkedIds>
        <linkedId>
            <idOfElement>ID-element-1</idOfElement>
            <idOfEffect>ID-effect-2</idOfEffect>
            <idOfEffect>ID-effect-1</idOfEffect>
        </linkedId>
        <linkedId>
            <idOfElement>ID-element-2</idOfElement>
            <idOfEffect>ID-effect-2</idOfEffect>
            <idOfEffect>ID-effect-4</idOfEffect>
            <idOfEffect>ID-effect-7</idOfEffect>
        </linkedId>
    </linkedIds>
</elements>
```

and (you can set the parameter `effects-url` in the stylesheet as needed to your file name)

```
<effects>
    <effect>
        <idEffect>ID-effect-1</idEffect>
        <name>NAME1</name>
    </effect>
    <effect>
        <idEffect>ID-effect-2</idEffect>
        <name>NAME2</name>
    </effect>
    <effect>
        <idEffect>ID-effect-4</idEffect>
        <name>NAME4</name>
    </effect>
    <effect>
        <idEffect>ID-effect-7</idEffect>
        <name>NAME7</name>
    </effect>
</effects>
```

are transformed into

```
<html lang="en">
   <body>
      <div>
         <div>
            <p>NAME1</p>
         </div>
         <div>
            <p>NAME2</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <div>
            <p>NAME2</p>
         </div>
         <div>
            <p>NAME4</p>
         </div>
         <div>
            <p>NAME7</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Should it look like this? http://pastebin.com/90wMQiMm

Comment: @SuperM4n, I have edited the answer and provided a complete XSLT 1.0 stylesheet showing how to use the two keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, now it's very clear to me how it works.